# What matrix operation performs a sort of "dot product"

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm looking for a matrix operation that does something like the following:
$$
\
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.39 & -0.8 & 0.24      \\    
\end{bmatrix}
(operation)
\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\1\\2\\3\\4    
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.39*0 & -0.8*0 & 0.24*0\\
    0.39*1 & -0.8*1 & 0.24*1\\
    0.39*2 & -0.8*2 & 0.24*2\\
    0.39*3 & -0.8*3 & 0.24*3\\
    0.39*4 & -0.8*4 & 0.24*4 
\end{bmatrix}
\
$$

Obviously this can be constructed by performing individual calculations on 3 5x3 matrices, where each row is 0 except for the one desired to be multiplied, but I thought that there had to be some defined operation that performs this calculation. Like a matix dot product or something

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Comment: @Semiclassical That's it, thankyou so much. It felt like an operation like that had to exist, I'd just never heard of it.